# How can i create a line chart of a specific row from my table in PANDAS?

Tags: pandas, charts, line

```
      PARENT    Week    Month   Weekend
---------------------------------------
1010D   AX1      665    1633    687
1009A   BX1     1372    1484    1173 
1013B   CX1      895     941    777 
1007B   DX1      829     932    773
```

This is my mydata.csv. (sorry i couldn't align the row values under specific columns asking the question with stackoverflow format.  @glhr

How can a draw a line chart of BX1 under **NAME** column for values of Week, Month and Weekend using Pandas?

Comment: Do you need `df.loc[df['NAME'] == 'BX1', ['Week','Month','Weekend']].plot()` ? What values are ploting from sample data? There is possible duplicated `BX1` ?

Comment: ya, it should working if multiple values `BX1`, if only one, then not.

Comment: #jezrael <br/> I am using the following code but pandas is  showing blank chart <br/>import pandas as pd<br/> <br>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt <br/>
%matplotlib inline <br/>
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')  <br/>
df.loc[df['NAME'] == 'BX1', ['Week','Month','Weekend']].plot() <br/>

Comment: if unique values `BX1`, it is expected. So you need transpose first and then plot by `df.loc[df['NAME'] == 'BX1', ['Week','Month','Weekend']].T.plot()` ?

Comment: @jezrael BX1 has 3 values - Week = 1372, Month = 1484 and Weekend  = 1173. just needing the code to extract BX1 row and plot its Week/Weekend/ Month values on a simple line or bar chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only unique value `BX1` value after filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) transpose and add [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) for convert one column `DataFrame` to `Series` and plot by [`plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df.loc[df['NAME'] == 'BX1', ['Week','Month','Weekend']].T.squeeze().plot.bar()
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df['NAME'] == 'BX1', ['Week','Month','Weekend']].T.squeeze().plot()
```

Comment: exactly what i needed! Thank you @jezrael.

Comment: did it! Thank you. I am totally new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Nice use of squeeze. :)

Comment: @anky_91 - Thank you :)